# Achieving responsive design with HERE maps and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, maps, here-api

I am learning bootstrap and I tried to use the HERE maps based on [this example from HERE](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/quick-start.html)

I realized, that to be able to use relative height (e.g. height: 50%) I have to make the css styles like that:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Now I would like to create two columns with bootstrap, left for itinerary and right for the map view.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    Here comes the itinerary
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="map">
  </div>
</div>
```

I quickly realized, that I have to use absolut size for the map element (e.g. width: 400px), otherwise the map is not displayed at all (when using height: 100%;) or the columns are stack from the beginning (using width: 100%;)

I suspect, that the reason for this lies in the width/height styling of the parent elements (row, container), but I do not know the right solution.

I also know, that after getting the styling right I need to take care about the automatic adapting of the maps size on window resize, but I would like go get the right styling first.

Comment: Just create a `div` with `id` of `map` inside `col-sm-8` and in CSS give it a height (for example: `#map { height: 400px; }`). It should work and should be responsive.

Comment: Putting the map div inside a col-sm-8 resolved the issue with width. I still would like to use relative height (fill-up the vertical space) of the map element.

Comment: Hmm, relative height to what? Browser height or something else?

Comment: I want add fixed-height header and footer and have two columns in between taking the rest of the vertical space, the left one filled with the map.

Comment: You can use the code provided in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/5V288/1025/

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295344/1173800

Answer (score 0):

From earlier reply from HERE support
"try this after the map object initialization:

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    map.getViewPort().resize(); 
});
That should solve the problem.
[How to redraw Here Map when container resizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197778/how-to-redraw-here-map-when-container-resizes/26295344#26295344)"